# SSD disk space loss after running Laravel Jobs - any solutions?

Tags: 20.04, disk-usage, laravel

**Overview**

Day before I had 20GB free space. Then I run laravel job and I got 0, then I deleted some files, cache and etc. and somehow I got 20GB more. Next day I run this jobs one more time and I got same.
Here some out put after I cleaned some snaps in `/var/lib/snapd/snaps/`

***df -h output***

```
udev            7,7G     0  7,7G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1,6G  3,3M  1,6G   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p2  137G  117G   13G  91% /
tmpfs           7,7G  336M  7,4G   5% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           7,7G     0  7,7G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop2      117M  117M     0 100% /snap/core/14946
/dev/loop9      6,5M  6,5M     0 100% /snap/curl/1679
/dev/loop10      56M   56M     0 100% /snap/cups/872
/dev/loop11     206M  206M     0 100% /snap/flutter/130
/dev/loop8      5,3M  5,3M     0 100% /snap/evince/1027
/dev/loop17     128K  128K     0 100% /snap/bare/5
/dev/loop6       64M   64M     0 100% /snap/core20/1891
/dev/loop14     165M  165M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/198
/dev/loop16     303M  303M     0 100% /snap/code/129
/dev/loop4       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2751
/dev/loop19      74M   74M     0 100% /snap/core22/634
/dev/loop29     112M  112M     0 100% /snap/slack/71
/dev/loop23     449M  449M     0 100% /snap/kf5-5-104-qt-5-15-8-core22/9
/dev/loop21     9,8M  9,8M     0 100% /snap/htop/3735
/dev/loop25     219M  219M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/93
/dev/loop39     170M  170M     0 100% /snap/postman/201
/dev/loop46      92M   92M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535
/dev/loop31     461M  461M     0 100% /snap/gnome-42-2204/102
/dev/loop38      13M   13M     0 100% /snap/snap-store/959
/dev/loop22     437M  437M     0 100% /snap/kde-frameworks-5-96-qt-5-15-5-core20/7
/dev/loop41     449M  449M     0 100% /snap/kf5-5-105-qt-5-15-9-core22/11
/dev/loop43     350M  350M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/140
/dev/loop40     351M  351M     0 100% /snap/zoom-client/205
/dev/loop36     235M  235M     0 100% /snap/okular/129
/dev/loop48     391M  391M     0 100% /snap/telegram-desktop/4798
/dev/loop47     324M  324M     0 100% /snap/kde-frameworks-5-qt-5-15-core20/14
/dev/loop52     438M  438M     0 100% /snap/kde-frameworks-5-98-qt-5-15-6-core20/9
/dev/nvme0n1p1  476M   36M  440M   8% /boot/efi
tmpfs           1,6G   20K  1,6G   1% /run/user/125
tmpfs           1,6G  7,0M  1,6G   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/loop53      54M   54M     0 100% /snap/snapd/19361
/dev/loop54     171M  171M     0 100% /snap/lxd/24918
/dev/loop28      54M   54M     0 100% /media/roma/disk
```

***Files screenshot:***

[files that shows disk space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcOdX.png)

***Disk Analyser***

[General screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqe4a.png)

[File usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqI8a.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have made an error when you installed your system with all the directories on one partition. See the Filesystem Hierarcy Standard at `https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/fhs.shtml`, or read `man hier`. The consequence of "everything on one partition" is that, if any application at all runs away and consumes all the disk space, that's  all the disk space there is, and your whole system fails. Sadly, the fix is an informed reinstall.

Enough Data Processing Philosophy!

One can use `find` (Read `man find xargs sudo`) and a temporary file to find the leftovers like this:

Just before running your `laravel` job,

```
touch /tmp/thumbtack
```

Run your `laravel` job.

Then,

```
sudo find / -anewer /tmp/thumbtack -print0 | \
    xargs -0 -r ls -ld
```

Comment: So what is wrong with my file system?
I installed it once on fresh SSD. I didn't touched anything that can broke something. Or maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: @Roma the problem is your Laravel job: it's misbehaving, and your system isn't able to handle it.

Comment: @Esther thanks.
I will investigate